# Collapsing a countable collection of intervals on $\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: gn.general-topology

Consider a countable collection $I_n$ of closed connected **disjoint** intervals on $\mathbb{S}^1$. When this collection is maximal, the set $\bigcap \nolimits_{i=1}^{n}( \mathbb{S}^1 \backslash  \bigcup \nolimits_{i=1}^{n} Int(I_n)\big )$ is the Cantor Space so such collection cannot exhaust the circle.

Is the result of collapsing each interval separately again $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the Bing shrinking criterion.

Comment: This should give you the idea:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function